# <img> overflowing vertically with 1fr height grid

Tags: html, css, flexbox, css-grid

I have a `<figure>` tag that is set to be displayed as a grid with an `<img>` and a `<figcaption>` inside. I want the image to take up the remaining vertical space left by the caption, without overflowing and without distorting the image's dimensions. I want the image to be able to be smaller than 100vh and 100vw, in case the image is smaller than the screen, but otherwise it should grow to the

I can't get the image to not overflow the height of the grid itself. It always overflow if the `<img>`'s source image is large enough to overflow.

My code is the following:

```css
.lightbox {
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
}

.lightbox figure {
  display: grid;
  max-height: 100%;
  grid-template-rows: 1fr min-content;
}

.lightbox figure img {
  min-height: 100%;
  min-width: 100%;
  object-fit: cover;
  vertical-align: bottom;
}

.lightbox figure figcaption {
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="lightbox">
  <figure>
    <div>
      <img src="https://placehold.co/6000x4000">
    </div>
    <figcaption>This is 1 caption for this image. Words Words Words. And some more words. We need to fill up some space here. Wahey.</figcaption>
  </figure>
</div>
```

Strangely enough, when I do `grid-template-rows` instead of `grid-template-columns`, then it'll work and the `<img>` and `<figcaption>` are taking up the horizontal space exactly. It's just when I do it with `grid-template-columns` that it breaks. What am I doing wrong here? Is there some magic about vertical size on `<img>` that I'm not aware of?

Comment: try `height: auto;  width: 100%;` for your image and remove your `div` inside `figure` tag

Comment: You have given min-width, min-height do you mean width and height?

Comment: @AHaworth I did and I think this just fixed all my issues ‍♀️

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.lightbox {
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
}

.lightbox figure {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-rows: 1fr min-content;
  max-height: 100%;
}

.lightbox figure img {
  width: 100%;
  max-height: 100%;
  min-height: 0;
  object-fit: cover;
}

.lightbox figure figcaption {
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="lightbox">
  <figure>
    <img src="https://placehold.co/6000x4000">
    <figcaption>This is 1 caption for this image. Words Words Words. And some more words. We need to fill up some space here. Wahey.</figcaption>
  </figure>
</div>
```